# What operating systems do Chinese satellites use?

Tags: artificial-satellite, software

Which operating systems are most frequently used by China for satellites?

Comment: Private chinese companies, .e.g. telecommunications, or government missions?

Comment: I guess its more interesting to know about both.

Comment: @Polygnome in this country's case, is there really a difference?

Comment: A good number of their satellites are part of the Beidou constellations. Beidou has some technical information on their site (beidou.gov.cn), but a lot of it is in Chinese, so it could take a while to wade through to find operating system information, if it's there.

Comment: The operating system is mentioned briefly in this news article, but not named: http://www.chinadailyasia.com/article/138936